Best Approach to Dynamically Retrieve Models in Laravel Request Classes via Route Parameters?
I’m building an abstract functionality in Laravel to dynamically retrieve models in the Request classes using route parameters. While this approach works, I’m concerned it may lead to future issues and am looking for feedback or a better alternative
My approach is the following:
Controller:
LinkController

Models in the request
[
    "project" => "Models\Project\ProjectLink"
    "link" => "Models\Project\Project"
]

Route:
/api/v2/project/{project}/link/{link}

Then i filter the models and return the one that corresponds with the controller:
Str::contains('Link Controller', ['project', 'link'], true)
// bool(true)

I’m matching the model dynamically based on the controller, so in this case, the Link model is matched because it corresponds with LinkController.
Here’s my current implementation in the Request class:
public function model(): ?Model
    {
        if ($this->cachedModel !== null) {
            return $this->cachedModel;
        }

        $request = request();
        $route = $request?->route();
        $parameters = $route?->parameters() ?? [];

        if (empty($parameters)) {
            return null;
        }

        $controllerClass = class_basename($route->getControllerClass());
        $controllerClassHeadLine = Str::headline($controllerClass);

        $filteredValues = array_filter(array_values($parameters), function($parameter) use ($controllerClassHeadLine) {
            return $parameter instanceof Model && Str::contains(
                $controllerClassHeadLine,
                explode('_', Str::snake(class_basename($parameter))),
                true
            );
        });

        return $this->cachedModel = reset($filteredValues) ?: null;
    }

